# NU1202 error VS17 compiling error

Tags: .net, visual-studio, entity-framework, nuget

Error   NU1202  Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet 2.0.0 supports: netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0)

I tried running this in the package manager console that I found on a previous answer but it didn't work:

```
dotnet nugget locals all --clear
```

Comment: update your .Net Core application to 2.x (2.1 for longest support)

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: The issue has not been resolved yet. When I try to update this, it doesn't have that option. So I redownloaded it and it told me to repair it, which I did. Still having the same error.

Answer (score 0):

> NU1202 error VS17 compiling error

The error messages give the all the things:

> Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet 2.0.0 supports:
>   **netcoreapp2.0** (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0)

So, to resolve this issue, you should update your target framework from `netcoreapp1.0` to `netcoreapp2.0`.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: My drop down just has ".net framework", so I went to "Install other frameworks" to get '.net core 2.0' and it lead to me to a repair .net core screen. I completed this with no errors, but I'm still getting this same error.